# How to maximize a form in a Tpanel using delphi

Tags: delphi, tform, tpanel

i'm trying to dynamically show a form in a TPanel
using this function

```
procedure Show_form_in_panel(form: TForm; Panel: Tpanel);
begin
  form.Parent := Panel;
  form.Show;   
  form.WindowState := wsMaximized;
end;
```

the form is showing very normal but he's not maximized in my panel and also i want to make this form automaticly react like components that have the Alight property = (alClient)

Comment: Have you tried using `alClient`? That's how I do it.

Comment: Showing a `TForm` inside a `TPanel` sounds unusrual to me. Is this supposed to work? Have you considered using a `TFrame` instead of a `TForm`?

Comment: @Wosi It's perfectly normal practice.

Comment: @JerryDodge Thanks. I read for the first time that someone wants to show a form in a panel. In the projects I have worked on there have always been TFrames for sharing the same piece of UI over different places. Is there any advantage of using a form in a panel?

Comment: @Wosi it works very normal .

Comment: @Wosi One big advantage of doing this is for example docking or undocking - or a form which might also be used elsewhere on its own. After all, a form is just another control, and other win controls are also just other windows. You can pop-out a panel or other controls and treat them as bordered forms also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to make this form automatically react like components that have the `Align` property set to `alClient`.

That's the solution. Remove

```
form.WindowState := wsMaximized;
```

and replace with

```
form.Align := alClient;
```